# Passing list from function to class in Python

Tags: python, list, class, reference

I am looking to bring out a function `load_words` from a class `Game` (since it really isn't dependent on the class - rather the opposite). And yet be able to reference and use the list I create in `load_words` in the class. How should I do that?

```py
class Game: 
    def __init__(self, words_file, matrix_size):
        self._words_file = words_file
        self._matrix_size = matrix_size
        self._attempt_count = 0
        if matrix_size % 2 != 0: 
            raise Exception("Invalid matrix size, has to be an even number, size now =%d" % matrix_size)
        self.load_words()
        if len(self._words) < matrix_size * matrix_size // 2:
            raise Exception(
                "Words list is too small for matrix of %d cells, words=%d"  
                % (matrix_size, len(self._words))
            )

    def load_words(self):  
        self._words = set() 
        with open(self._words_file) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                line = line.strip()
                if line != "":
                    self._words.add(line)
```

Comment: Yes, you just have to move the method to a function using the rules of refactoring. I'll do that in PyCharm to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this. There are many combinations as the other answers demonstrate.

```py
def load_words(file, words):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if line != "":
                words.add(line)

class Game:
    def __init__(self, words_file, matrix_size):
        self._words_file = words_file
        self._matrix_size = matrix_size
        self._attempt_count = 0
        if matrix_size % 2 != 0:
            raise Exception("Invalid matrix size, has to be an even number, size now =%d" % matrix_size)
        self._words = set()
        load_words(self._words_file, self._words)
        if len(self._words) < matrix_size * matrix_size // 2:
            raise Exception(
                "Words list is too small for matrix of %d cells, words=%d"
                % (matrix_size, len(self._words))
            )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways I guess, and by the way your initial code is valid too. If you insist of bringing `load_words` outside of the class, than something like that would work:

```py
class Game: 
    def __init__(self, words_file, matrix_size):
        # your code
    
    def load_words_to_class(self, words):
        self._words = words
        # rest of the code to check what you want with self._words

def load_words(self):  
    # your code to load words
    game = Game()
    game.load_words_to_class(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the words to `Game.__init__` as an argument. Whether that list comes from a hard-coded list or read from a file is irrelevant. A separate class method can be used to get the words from a file.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, words, matrix_size):
        self._words_file = words_file
        self._matrix_size = matrix_size
        self._attempt_count = 0
        if matrix_size % 2 != 0: 
            raise Exception("Invalid matrix size, has to be an even number, size now =%d" % matrix_size)
        if len(self._words) < matrix_size * matrix_size // 2:
            raise Exception(
                "Words list is too small for matrix of %d cells, words=%d"  
                % (matrix_size, len(self._words))
            )

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, word_file, matrix_size):  
        words = {}
        with open(words_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if line != "":
                    words.add(line)
        return cls(words, matrix_size)

g = Game.from_file("words.txt", 20)
```

As an added feature, rather than force the caller to calculate the size, consider *computing* the matrix size from whatever list of words is provided.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self._words_file = words_file
        self._matrix_size = matrix_size
        self._attempt_count = 0 
        self.matrix_size = math.sqrt(len(self._words)*2)  # roughly

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, word_file):  
        words = {}
        with open(words_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if line != "":
                    words.add(line)
        return cls(words)

g = Game.from_file("words.txt")
```

---

To simplify the design further, you might recognize that reading words from a file is not really specific to the `Game` class, but at the same time the particular file format may make such a function not generally usable outside the class, by defining a private *static* method.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self._words_file = words_file
        self._matrix_size = matrix_size
        self._attempt_count = 0 
        self.matrix_size = math.sqrt(len(self._words)*2)  # roughly

    @staticmethod
    def _read_words_from_file(word_file):
        with open(words_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if line != "":
                    yield line

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, word_file):  
        words = set(cls._read_words_from_file(word_file))
        return cls(words)

g = Game.from_file("words.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you! Also very nice touch your last comment, just implemented that too